# How to change the button color using ng-click function?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I got the buttons list from resource. It consist of 10 buttons like 
t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10

When I click the on t1 button  first time button color change  to red. Second time I click on same button color change to green.

Please tell me how to do this

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1 col-md-1" ng-repeat="table in tables" style="margin-left:1px">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="getTable(table)">{{table.tablename}}</button>
</div>
```

this is my method

```
 $scope.ng-click=gettable(table){
  //
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Just bind one more property with your all the items in tables array like this-

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tables.length; i++)
{
    $scope.tables[i].btnClass = "btn-success";
}
```

then in HTML, assign this class like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn {{table.btnClass}}" ng-click="getTable(table)">
{{table.tablename}}</button>
```

and ng-click function as:

```
$scope.getTable = function(table) {
    table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "btn-info" ? "btn-success" : "btn-info"
}
```

Or if you want to change manual colors then create one class in css like this:

```
.red-button {
    background-color: "red";
}
```

Then in the function

```
$scope.getTable = function(table) {
    table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "red-button" ? "btn-success" : "red-button"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.first time click on button btn-info is activated. but second time i click on the same button btn-success is not applied.

Comment: here how to set Default color is green for button. for loop not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion: Inside your `$scope.ng-click=gettable(table){ ...... }`

- Create an array of colors
- Everytime the button clicks, pull a random color value inside that array

Answer (score 0):

Using the controllerAs syntax (which I advise you to use), you can work with the following.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="table in ctrl.tables">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.getTable(table)" ng-style="{ 'background-color': table.color }">{{table.tablename}}</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
this.getTable = function(table) {
    table.color = "red";
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/axzyUQJowlSEClszrIQs

Comment: how to set default color green for  button

Comment: Well just use the style attribute on the button...
<button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.getTable(table)" ng-style="{ 'background-color': table.color }" style="background-color: green;">{{table.tablename}}</button>

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors=['red','green','yellow','black','blue'];
$scope.color=null;
$scope.ng-click=gettable(table){ 
var colorToApply=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
$scope.color=colorToApply
 }
```

Now you can define css rule here

```
.green{
  color:green;
}
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
.red{
  color:red;
}
.yellow{
  color:yellow;
}
```

Then in your view you can set ng-style on the button you want to change color and bind it to color in the scope like

```
<button ng-style="color">Change color</button>
```